# Need help updating code options.headless = False

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help updating my code. I understand selenium has updated their headless arg but I'm not sure how to fix my current code to meet these changes. Please see code below and the error I get when running it.

**Current Code:**

```
#Initiate Chrome Driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False # Make it True for headless
if options.headless:
    options.add_argument('--log-level 3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

**Error Message:**

```
DeprecationWarning: headless property is deprecated, instead check for '--headless' in arguments
if options.headless:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\Patric\\Downloads\\HIT_Interns.v2.py", line 18, in \<module\>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

I tried changing the code to use `.add_argument("--headless")` and `.add_argument("--headless=new")` but neither worked for me. I know I am missing something but not sure what.

Comment: This question was closed by a moderator, but it’s not really the answer. it must be a new bug in Selenium with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firefox, maybe this could be helpful:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options) 
driver.get('https://www.qwant.com/?l=en')

print(driver.title)
# scraping logic...

# release the resources allocated by Selenium
# and shut down the browser
driver.quit()
```